# Can "fascination" convey its right meaning in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I wrote this sentence as follows.

> I learned that my utter fascination lies in computer science.

I want to use this sentence to express my love and passion in computer science. But I know that “fascination” has another meaning as “glamour”. So I am not sure whether this sentence can be misunderstood as “my glamour come from computer science.”

So if there does exist ambiguous meaning, which sentence can I use to convey my initial meaning?

Comment: I would say that you have a fascination _for_ or _with_ computer science, not that it _lies in_ it.

Comment: Thank you! May I ask that why "lies in" should not be used here? Will it bring the ambiguous meaning or is it not suitable to get together with "fascination"? If I use the sentence "I learned my utter fascination for computer science.", can it express my initial meaning reightly without other ambiguous meanings?

Comment: It is not suitable _in this particular sentence_. You could say "The fascination which computer science has for me lies in [whatever it is about it that appeals so much to you]".  With regard to your original sentence, I would suggest "I found that I had a fascination with computer science."

Comment: OK. I understand. Thank you so much again! And I have one more little question. The complete sentence is “Since then, I have had a passion to learn programming on my own, and I found that I had a fascination with computer science.” 

Here I want to strengthen the extent of my passion in the second compound sentence. So which adjective is suitable to get together with “fascination” to strengthen my tone? How about “I found that I had a strong fascination with computer science.” or “utter fascination”?

Comment: 'Had a strong fascination' or 'was utterly fascinated by'.

Comment: Many thanks for your help! I thought the latter sounds better and then I searched online and found that “be fascinated with” implies I am more actively engaged than “be fascinated by” ([link](https://www.quora.com/Which-is-correct-fascinated-with-or-fascinated-by)). So I think I may find the best solution with your help, i.e. “Since then, I have had a passion to learn programming on my own, and I found that I was utterly fascinated with computer science.” I really appreciate your help!  : )

Answer (score 0):

This sentence will not be misunderstood as "my glamor lies in computer science". However, it does not read naturally "fascination" here is a *thing*, soemthign that you have. So you could write:

- > I learned that I have an utter fascination with computer science.
- > I learned that I am  utterly fascinated by computer science.
- > I learned that I have a strong passion for computer science.
- > I learned that I have a strong interest in computer science.
- > I learned that my main interest lies in computer science.

The last sentence implies a comparison with other, lesser, interests you might also have. The meanings of the first four are pretty much the same.

Answer (score 0):

***Fascination*** and ***Glamour*** were *historically* related words, though never quite synonymous. Today, in modern usage, the words are *completely distinct* and have *very* different meanings.  There are no situations I can think of where you can substitute one for the other.  The modern usage of ***fascination*** is "a very strong interest you have which causes you to pay deep and close attention to something, often a hobby or field of study".  The modern usage of ***glamour*** is mostly "beautiful and exciting", with a strong subtext of "famous and successful" and more than a hint of "sexually attractive".  For example, celebrities are often depicted with glamour.

(Side note: ***glamour*** by itself is somewhat less commonly used than its adjective form, ***glamorous***, as ***glamour*** is slightly abstract... but in general, you can say "I *have* glamour" or "I *am* glamourous" and it means more or less the same thing)

As the two words have very distinct meanings in modern usage, no one will ever mistake a word meaning an extremely strong interest in something with a word meaning beautiful (and more).

All that said, you should be aware that the sentence you wrote, while *grammatically* correct, is not a natural English construction.  This is because your ***fascination*** does not *do* anything, it is a trait that you have.  So ***fascination*** should never be followed by a verb.  Instead, you could ***have a fascination with/for*** , or change it into ***be fascinated with*** .

(Disclaimer: Exceptions exist, but are complicated, uncommon, and usually poetic.  As a student, I would advise you not to bother with the exceptions for now.)

Your sentence:

> I learned that my utter fascination lies in computer science.

Here, "my utter fascination" is strangely followed with the verb "lies".  Again, fascinations shouldn't do things, even "lie somewhere".  So now we should apply the corrections I mentioned above:

> 1. I learned that I have an utter fascination for computer science.

> 2. I learned that I am utterly fascinated with computer science.

These are much more natural.

Comment: You say that "fascination should never be followed by a verb". I honestly don't see why not. "Fascination" is a noun and perfectly capable of being the subject of a sentence. I see nothing at all wrong with "My fascination lies in computer science". Though "My fascination is for..." might be more usual.